# C strcmp - compare strings declared by char and char*

Tags: c, string, strcmp

I am trying to compare 2 strings using the below code:

```
char a[100] = "\0";
char* b[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    b[i] = "";
b[0] = "xy";
a[0] = 'x';
a[1] = 'y';
int c = strcmp(a, b[0]);
```

I think both `a` and `b[0]` contain the string `"xy"`, so I expect `int c` equal 0. However the result stored in `int c` is -858993460.
Why would that happen? What should I do in order to avoid this fault? Thank you very much.

Update: I found that there is some error on my computer...

```
char a[3] = { NULL };
char d[3] = { NULL };
a[0] = 'x';
a[1] = 'y';
a[2] = '\0';

d[0] = 'x';
d[1] = 'y';
d[2] = '\0';
int c = strcmp(a, d);
```

Even using this code, I got `int c` to be a negative value. I have no idea why that happened.

Comment: Strings in C are null terminated. When you compare strings means two null terminated strings.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a duplicate. Anyone?

Comment: this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997095/comparing-null-terminated-string-with-a-non-null-terminated-string-in-c

Comment: To add to the answers, you have not allocated memory for b.

Comment: Placing the code into a `main() and feeding to a C compiler cannot reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] which includes the part where you print the value of `c`. I strongly suspect that you are printing the value of some other (unitialised) variable.

Comment: [MSVC fills uninitialized memory with 0xCC to help debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714), and -858993460 = 0xCCCCCCCC

Answer (score 2):

It is undefined behaviour because `a` is not null terminated. All string in C have to be null terminated to be used in `strcmp`. What `strcmp` does is looping over the two strings until either one of the two is NULL terminated (see  [Implementation of strcmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34873209/implementation-of-strcmp/34873406) to get an idea of how it works).
You can see that if `'\0'` is not present anywhere you got a problem there.

Read [Why do strings in C need to be null terminated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221304/why-do-strings-in-c-need-to-be-null-terminated) for more info: